# Nodejs Audio Stream - Main Producing Client -> Server -> Multiple client listeners

Tags: node.js, audio, http-live-streaming, internet-radio

I want to build an internet radio station using nodejs. My architecture needs to be like the following, there is one producer who records live audio, this live audio data needs to be sent to the server. On the server-side, I need to save the live streams of audio data in some audio format(for future playback) and also simultaneously stream the live audio to multiple clients. Can somebody please point me towards some implementations or library available to achieve this? I have read several posts and stackoverflow answers but couldn't find anything related to my need.

Is webRTC needed? I don't want clients to get peer to peer connection as I also want to save the live audio on the server. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  How you capture the audio and get it to the server depends a lot on what platforms you plan to put this on.  The specifics of what you're using to stream depend on your latency and quality requirements.  How you store the audio depends on how you want to access it later.  For the purposes of Stack Overflow questions, if you can break down your question into pieces, with more details.

Comment: I have a mic with a soundcard that will be used to record the audio. I am connecting that mic to my pc. I need to send this live stream of audio and save this on the server in mp3, wav, etc format and simultaneously stream to other clients. I was hoping websockets would solve the issue. I don't need a very detailed answer on each and every step. I just need an idea to get started so that later when I get stuck on a specific part I could come to SO and ask that relevant question.

Comment: You're sending that audio to the server via web browser?  Custom native client?  What OS?  What sort of latency requirement do you have?  (Does it need to be realtime, like voice chat, or are a few seconds of latency acceptable?)  The folks listening... how are they listening?  Also via browsers?  Media Devices API, FFmpeg, HLS, should get you started.

Comment: Yes, the audio needs to be sent from the web browser to the server. A latency of 1-2 seconds is fine. The listeners would be listening from a mobile app android/ios. This is basically like internet radio. I don't know how to process the audio bytes coming in to the server. How would I save the live audio stream on the server and also stream those bytes to other clients simultaneously?

Comment: If the latency needs to be as low as 1-2 seconds, you need to use WebRTC all around.  This doesn't mean you distribute peer to peer... the server becomes one of the "peers".  You'll have extremely low latency, at the tradeoff of quality, constant resampling (to keep latency low), and complexity and cost.  If your latency can be a few seconds higher, you can simply encode to a segmented format such as HLS, and then you get your past recording and streaming method all in one go.  It can be served with any web server, and playable client-side with any HLS client, such as HLS.js.